# Flex direction: row-reverse in react-native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

How can i reproduce [`flex-direction: row-reverse`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/) in React-Native? When in element' style i'm doing:

```
 flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
```

i'm getting error:

> Invalid prop `flexDirection` of value `row-reverse` supplied to
>   `StyleSheet`

UPDATE: They just [added it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d43e0db81e86d4d03638cd17034086717fe715a3) in version 0.29.0 :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***UPDATE***

As of v29, React Native provides support for reverse flex directions in Android and iOS.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.29.0

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER***

There is no `row-reverse` or `column-reverse` in react-native.

See this [table of supported attributes](https://github.com/facebook/css-layout#supported-attributes):

[image]

https://github.com/facebook/css-layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexDirection` property and give it a value `'row-reverse'` with new version.

Sample code:

```
flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
```

Proof:
[image]